# Combine two rows to make it a single row

Tags: html, css

I need to combine two rows in a table into a single row so that I can apply a style (background with a gradient) on that row.

I tried to use rowspan on a table cell with colspan = number of total columns but that does not work.

Tried to use a nested table inside the main table header, but in that case the table background does not have the desired style.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Debarupa/EyxkJ/3/

If you look at the demo, I need to have "Additional Info" and the column headers merged to a single row so that the style 'gridheader' can be applied to them as one row.

Ideas anyone? Thanks for any assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using two different classes for top two rows you want to combine. Then break gradient onto two, for each of these rows with color changing 0-50% for the first one and 50-100% for the second one.

Here is the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/EyxkJ/5/

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution though.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/EyxkJ/7/) with nested table into table cell for the header.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually tried the same yesterday and it was not working because I have another style applied to the table and that was getting precedence. Please see the edited fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Debarupa/EyxkJ/12/) for the "actual" case. As this is not something you knew and was totally my fault not including that other style, I'm upvoting you as this solution indeed works in a normal situation.